# ¿Cómo filtro solo los valores de la columna PartnerDesc que estén en la columna ReporterDesc?

Tags: r, exportar

**Quiero que me queden en la columna de PartnerDesc(países que importan) solo los valores que están en ReporterDesc(países que exportan) y que las filas de países que exportan a los países que reciben pero no exportan se eliminen.**

ReporterDesc   PartnerDesc           total_value

1 China                 US                  577125499929

2 China          Hong Kong SAR China      401691808987.

3 Mexico              US                  386086717587

4 Canada              US                  377983779658.

5 China               China Hong Kong SAR 349442324674

6  US                  Canada              306926753196

7 Germany             US                  289208052449.

8 US                  Mexico              276458852053

9 Germany             China               247170542182.

10 Germany             France              242000704612.

Por ejemplo, en este dataframe eliminar la fila 10 ya que Francia no aparece en la fila de ReporterDesc.

Comment: Agrega el código para ver que has intentando y como te podemos ayudar, StackOverflow no es para hacer tareas.

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Ya lo solucione con el siguiente código:                                                   
    definitivo<-links[links$PartnerDesc %in% links$ReporterDesc, ]